# a mix of transpose, sequence and query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

hello masters of google sheet or app-scrippt;

I am facing another problem, which would need me (with my knowledge so far) to do 4 steps to get the final result. i wonder if my problem could get solved a little more the gentle way without needing 4 helper lists.

my original has one column (col A) with unique numbers and either 2 or 3 names per row (col B, C, D):

at the end i would like to have only 2 columns like

[image: start with this]
[image: end with this]

any hints to get rid of 4 helper-lists? I don´t like my way to transpose first, then query every single column ..... and my solution is not dynamic. ;(
PLEASE note: it doesn't matter if one cell in a row is empty. the sequence is always 3!!!

best scenario would even be to sort each row / sequence based on values which are in another worksheet (NAME COLUMN: B; VALUE COLUMN C) so index would be the same for all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `best scenario would even be to sort each row / sequence based on values which are in another worksheet (NAME COLUMN: B; VALUE COLUMN C) so index would be the same for all.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By the way, in your tags, `google-apps-script` is included. Your goal is to achieve using Google Apps Script?

Comment: sorry, my english isn´t the best. with best scenario I was going one step further, and could not imagine that this will/would work without a script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that several answers have been posted. I think that they will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need...

```
={INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(QUERY(F2:F9," where F is not null ",0)&"@",3),"@"))),
        FLATTEN(G2:I9)}
```

[image]

*(please -as always- adjust formula according to your ranges and locale)*

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REPT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134)

Comment: that´s exactly what I need, beside the fact that your formula puts everything in one column, which is strange to me. so I cut your formula  and put the second flatten-formula (never heard before) into the next cell. thank you so much

Comment: *"...beside the fact that your formula puts everything in one column"*.  That happens because you have a different locale in your sheet. You probably need to use `;` instead of the `,`. As mentioned: *"**Always** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale"*

Answer (score 0):

```
function pivotb() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//data sheet
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() -1,4).getValues();
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');//output sheet
  let obj = {pA:[]};
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      obj[r[0]]=[];
      obj.pA.push(r[0]);
      let t=r.slice();
      t.shift();
      t.forEach(e=>{
        if(e) {
          obj[r[0]].push(e);
        }
      });
    };
  });
  let oA=[['Number','Name']];//output array with headers
  obj.pA.forEach(p=>{
    obj[p].forEach(e=>{
      oA.push([p,e])
    });
  });
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your unprocessed data as shown were in a sheet called Sheet1, place the following formula into cell A1 of a new sheet:

`=ArrayFormula({"number","name"; SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A&"~"&Sheet1!B2:D,Sheet1!A2:A<>"")),"~",1,0)})`

This will produce both headers and all results in accordance with your desired layout.

You can change the header labels within the formula as you like.

The rest concatenates the value of every cell in A:A with a tilde (~) to every value in B:D for each respective row.

`FILTER` keeps only those entries where A:A is not null.

`FLATTEN` makes one column out of all the concatenations.

`SPLIT` splits at the tilde into three columns (noting that the final parameter of `SPLIT` is 0, which means "don't remove nulls from the results).